# Pyspark Code with all Libraries Deployment in EMR

Tags: pyspark, deployment, dependencies, amazon-emr, miniconda

I am creating a `Pyspark` Data Engineering project first time from the scratch using `Conda`. I already did many using `Scala-Spark` and `Maven`. For Scala-Spark, using Maven assembly plugin, I create the Jar with all the dependencies available in the `pom.xml` file. Then add the Jar to the `S3` and run from `EMR` `Step`. For any new dependenies/libraries, just need to add to the pom.xml file, Build and create the new Jar and then replace with the jar to the S3.

I want to do the same using `Pyspark`. I am using `Conda` to manage dependencies/libraries and environment on `Local` `Pycharm`. But I don't know how to build and run the full Pyspark project with all the dependencies/libraries to `EMR`. How to add new dependencies to EMR when new dependencies need to be added in the code. Has anybody built this kind Pyspark project with the dependencies in EMR? Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you!!